# Creating a callback system using closures

Tags: closures, rust

I'm trying to make something like a "callback system". For example, there is a window and a couple of buttons in it. The window sets callbacks for each button. Both callbacks should change the state of the window. The compiler doesn't allow capturing `&self` in my closures / callbacks, and I don't know how to make it work.

Are there any common patterns for callbacks I should be following?

This is an easy example as all components have the same lifetime. What if the components have different lifetimes?

```rust
struct Button<'a> {
    f: Option<Box<Fn() + 'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Button<'a> {
    fn new() -> Button<'a> { Button { f: None } }
    fn set<T: Fn() + 'a>(&mut self, f: T) { self.f = Some(Box::new(f)); }
    fn unset(&mut self) { self.f = None; }
    fn call(&self) { match self.f { Some(ref f) => f(), None => () } }
}

struct Window<'a> {
    btn: Button<'a>,
    //btns: Vec<Button<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Window<'a> {
    fn new() -> Window<'a> {
        Window { btn: Button::new() }
    }

    fn hi(&mut self) { // self is mutable
        println!("callback");
    }

    fn run(&mut self) {
        // Compile error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for
        // capture of `self` by closure due to conflicting requirements
        self.btn.set(|| self.hi()); // How to make it work?
        self.btn.call();
        self.btn.unset();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut wnd = Window::new();
    wnd.run();
}
```

Comment: Also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32044301/cannot-pass-self-as-callback-parameter-due-to-double-borrowing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are going to run into immediate problems with this line:

```
self.btn.set(|| self.hi());
```

Here, you need to borrow `self` as mutable in order to modify `btn`. You are *also* trying to borrow `self` as mutable in the closure. This is going to immediately run into problems because Rust does not allow you to have multiple mutable references to the same object (known as *aliasing*). This is a fundamental part of the the memory-safety guarantees of the language.

Also, conceptually you are trying to set up a cycle of references - the `Window` knows about `Button` and `Button` knows about `Window`. While this is possible, it often isn't what you want. Once the references have a cycle, it's very hard to disentangle them. You can also search other questions that ask about creating *graphs* in Rust (as opposed to *trees*) to see similar issues other people have had.

Ideally, you can structure your code as a tree. Here, I chose that `Button` can know about `Window`, but not vice versa:

```rust
struct Button<'a> {
    f: Option<Box<FnMut() + 'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Button<'a> {
    fn new() -> Button<'a> { Button { f: None } }
    fn set<T: FnMut() + 'a>(&mut self, f: T) { self.f = Some(Box::new(f)); }
    fn unset(&mut self) { self.f = None; }
    fn call(&mut self) { match self.f { Some(ref mut f) => f(), None => () } }
}

struct Window;

impl Window {
    fn hi(&mut self) {
        println!("callback");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut wnd = Window;
    let mut btn = Button::new();
    btn.set(|| wnd.hi());
    btn.call();
    btn.unset();
}
```

Comment: Does this mean that I cannot write a button which changes his own title on click? See [the code](http://is.gd/xW4sGp)

Comment: Actually I can. Post click events to an queue and handle them in main loop as you want. [The complete example](http://is.gd/X39182)