# Cannot pass self as callback parameter due to double borrowing

Tags: rust

I'm trying to call closure that was saved inside a struct but I'd also like to pass the struct as an argument to the closure. Here's the specific piece of code.

```
pub fn react(&mut self) -> &mut Button {
   if let Some(ref mut c) = self.click_callback {
            c(self);
    }
    self
}
```

Note that self is a `Button` and `self.click_callback` is an `Option<Box<Fn(&mut Button)>>`

So from what I understand the "if let" borrows self until its scopes ends, but then when I try to pass self as an argument it attempts to borrow it again. Is there anything specific I can do that will avoid this double borrow attempt?

Answer (score 8):

The simplest solution is to break the callback out from `self`, like so:

```
let callback = self.click_callback.take();
if let Some(ref mut c) = callback {
    c(self);
}
self.click_callback = callback;
self
```

This temporarily replaces `click_callback` with `None`, hence why you have to put it back when you're done.